# Display pdf inside webpage. document url is a variable

Tags: html, angularjs, pdf

I have a requirement of displaying a pdf inside a webpage. This pdf will be based on a list of option and onclick of any of the options, the corresponding url must be displayed in my webpage

My scope variable contains a list of objects. based on one property, the corresponding pdf(url contained in variable) must be displayed within the webpage. I tried using iframe and embed with url and src set to the scope variable(currentLandingUrl) but it is not working.

```
<embed src = currentLandingUrl type="application/pdf" id='some id'
       style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" />
```

i just see an empty div.

Comment: Are you using PHP for variable passing. if not then please post your try as well

Comment: Have you considered using [embed tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) instead of iframe? Also, what do you have in your server response under `Content-Disposition`?

Comment: <embed src = currentLandingUrl type="application/pdf" id='selected-document' style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"/> .

Comment: `<embed src="file.pdf" width="600px" height="500px" />`

Comment: Hi, my main question is that my src cannot be set to a direct value. It is a JavaScript variable whose value depends on user selection. Can anyone suggest a way.

Comment: Keep in mind that most modern browsers have deprecated and removed support for browser plug-ins, so relying upon `<embed>` is generally not wise if you want your site to be operable on the average user's browser. [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed)